# Probuilder API collapse shared vertices

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

for several hours I try to find a way to collapse/merge shared vertices in my mesh created with Probuilder API.

Does anyone know how possibly I could reduce the vertices amount?
I can get all shared vertices I can merge them to have only necessary vertices (reduced) but I can't figure out how to actually apply back this data to the mesh so it can rebuild and have new (reduced) amount of vertices...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your meshes procedurally in unity. For this take into account that it quite a low level an time demanding stuff (although it is so awesome).
For better advice if you are trying to do this yourself, you would need to share your attept and your code for more specific help. I am not familiar with probuilder, but you should be able to access to the [vertices](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) of the [mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) you create.

Meanwhile you can consider external tools to reduce your vertices or polygonst such as this [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/mesh-simplify-43658) to be used to solve your problem, or to check it souce code to be used as inspitarion.